# Open-sourcing code with Parse.com client key and application id safe?

Tags: security, github, parse-platform

I want to put my application that uses Parse on Github. Should I remove my application id and client key? Parse documentation says that "The application ID and client key are not secret, and by themselves they do not secure an app." I'd rather leave them so if people compile the app the database would be there and working, but I'm worried about the security of this, especially since it exposes my client id and I have some other apps on Parse under this account. How is it usually done?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/data

Comment: Some discussion about this here: https://parse.com/questions/securing-application-id-and-api-key-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an initial data-set with sample data as a JSON or CSV file for people to import, or include a Cloud Function that does the initial creation of all the classes if you just want empty tables.

I would recommend against including your own keys as you'll be liable if they exceed the limits of a free database.

Comment: Good point about free database limits, thanks! Empty tables is what I'd need, but checking out Cloud Code documentation it seems that you still have to include the application id and the API key. Should I instruct the user to put their own keys both there and in the setting up code, and run the cloud function immediately on app launch?

Comment: @p4sh4 Cloud Code does not require any keys, you don't need to call initialise there.